# How to consume the result of Image.prefetch in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, prefetch

I'm trying to prefetch an image using `Image.prefetch()` in an entry level component so that when the user navigates to a child component which displays the aforementioned image, it'll be ready to be displayed with less delay.

`Image.prefetch()` is mentioned under the Image topic in React Native documentation but I found the examples there fairly convoluted.

Can someone who used this feature explain how it would work for the simple use case I mentioned above?

Here's how I tried to implement it:

```
 // main.js

class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        let prefetch = Image.prefetch(this.props.url);
        return (
            <Content imgUrl={this.props.url}/>
        );
    }
}



// content.js
class Content extends Component {
    render() {
        const { imgUrl } = this.props;
        return (
            <Image source={imgUrl} />
        );
    }
}
```

The result of this implementation is an empty Image because it just returns a promise without an Image.

What am I missing here?

Comment: i'm having trouble with this too!

Answer (score 0):

You need to render Content *after* the prefetch is resolved:

```js
render() {
    Image.prefetch(this.props.url)
        .then(() => {
            return (
                <Content imgUrl={this.props.url} />
            );
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

You may also show the ActivityIndicator while prefetching inside the Main render, conditional on a state variable that changes its flag (true/false) when the prefetch is resolved so that the indicator disappears on that event.

Comment: Works for me. Did you click "run code snippet" or did you try integrating it into your app?